# Spring boot Web-Client Exception handling

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am trying to handle exception thrown by the downstream services and capture the error code as well as the error response message. After searching some solutions online I see the below common method of handling the exception but I am really not sure what exactly I have to write in my MyCustomConnectionException? By the way when I was using **Resttemplate** I was able to handle easily by throwing the **HttpClientResponseException** and capture everything but here am really not sure how this works? I am new in using Webclient and Spring reactive technology.
Could someone help me out here. ?

```
        Mono<String> result = client.get()
        .uri("/api/{id}", id).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, response -> {

             return Mono.error(new MyCustomConnectionException());
         })
        .bodyToMono(String.class);
```

Comment: You don't need any onStatus() call. By default, when an error response is received, a Mono.error() is returned with an instance of [WebClientResponseException](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClientResponseException.html). And as you can see, it allows accessing the status code and the body of the response

Answer (score 0):

Here MyCustomConnectionException class can throw any custom message you want to be return when any error occurs due to your web client configuration errors,such as incorrect URL or missing authentication keys.

Comment: welcome to stackoveflow. check this -https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic